# What's the modification of a Calabi-Yau manifold?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Recall that a modification of a compact manifold $X$ is a holomorphic map $\mu:\tilde X \to X$ such that:

i) dim $\tilde X$=dim $X$;

ii) there exists an analytic subset $S\subset X$ of codimension $\geq 1$ such that $\mu: X\backslash \mu^{-1}(S) \to X\backslash S$ is a biholomorphism.

The manifold $X$ is said to be in the Fujiki class $\mathcal C$, if $\tilde X$ is a compact Kähler manifold.
And a Calabi-Yau manifold is a compact Kähler manifold with canonical bundle trivial.

My question is: If $\tilde X$ is a Calabi-Yau manifold, then what is $X$? is $X$ in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ with canonical bundle trivial? If not, fix $X$ in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ with canonical bundle trivial, then what can we say about $\tilde X$?

The essence of this question is that how bimeromorphic map affect the canonical bundle, since any manifold in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ is bimeromorphic to a compact Kähler manifold. Does any one has any clue?

Comment: The canonical bundle will have a single nonvanishing section (up to scaling), corresponding to the determinant of the derivative of the map, and thus having a divisor supported where the map is not one-to-one.

Comment: @Will Sawin, what do you mean by "having a divisor supported where the map is not ono-to-one"? do you mean something happened in the part $\mu:\mu^{-1}(S)\to S$ and make $X$ can't admit a trivial canonical bundle?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.